# Call Async Webservice From For Loop

Tags: android

When I call a webservice from a for loop to insert/update data into MySQL using PHP only the last item gets inserted/updated because (i think) the for loop completes quicker than the webservice, how can I delay my for loop or achieve a webservice call for each item returned in the for loop one after another.

For Loop Code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {

                view = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, lv.getChildAt(i), lv);

                if (view != null) {

        // Getting my views
            tvItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
            strItem = tvItem.getText().toString();

        //Call AsyncTask
                    accessWebService();

                }
            }
```

Webservice:

```
    private class Webservice extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try{
            ld();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {

    Webservice task = new Webservice();

    //Update MySQL Using PHP

}
```

Comment: your current code will execute asynctask sequentially so it might be taking some extra time to finish executing all of them.

Comment: accessWebService(); use this in onPost. Create a  global count variable to store count value

Comment: @Vivek Mishra yes true

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert/update all data from for loop you must use callback like interfaces. Once you implement this it will wait for completing the process. Once completed it will call success or error method. Based on this you insert/update another record.

```
interface DataCallback {

    fun onSuccess(result: Any)

    fun onError(error: Any)
}

public void getCountries(new DataCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object result){
        // insert/update next record
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Object error){
        // show error message
    }

});
```

This is just example. You should convert it based on your need. Thanks.